proof of Robinson's test
I have a question about the proof of Robinson's test concearning model-complete theories. In particular, I'm trying to prove this implication:
Given an $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$, suppose that for all $\mathcal{M_1,M_2} \in \operatorname{Mod}(T)$ with $\mathcal{M_1} \subseteq \mathcal{M_2}$ and for all $\phi$ existential $\mathcal{L}(M_1)$-sentence, $\mathcal{M}_2 \models \phi$ implies $\mathcal{M}_1 \models \phi$, then every $\mathcal{L}$-formula is $T$-equivalent to a universal formula.
A question of this kind has already been asked on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321904
The hint given in the accepted answer is: prove that $T \cup \Sigma \cup \{\neg\phi\}$ is inconsistent, where $\Sigma=\{\psi \ | \ T \models \phi \rightarrow \psi, \ \psi \text{ a universal $\mathcal{L}(M_1)$-sentence}\}$. I see why this helps in concluding the proof, by I can't prove the hint itself.
Everything I can say starts with: suppose that such union of theories is consistent, i.e. there exists a model $\mathcal{M}$ for $T$, $\Sigma$ and $\lnot \phi$. In particular, it means that $\mathcal{M} \models \psi$ for all $\psi \in \Sigma$.
At this point I don't know how to go on; I have tried many ways but they don't work. For example, I thought that I could simply say that, supposing that $T \cup \Sigma \cup \{\phi\}$ is consistent, then there would exist a proof of $\phi$ using a finite number of formulas in $T \cup \Sigma(x)$, but I think that's not true since the theory is not complete.
In another way, for example, I tried so: from the absurd hypothesis, it follows that $\mathcal{M} \models \phi \rightarrow \psi$, so $\mathcal{M} \models \neg \psi \rightarrow \neg \phi$. Now I would like to say something to use the hypothesis of what I'm trying to prove, but I don't know how.

Can you clarify your question? Are you trying to prove that (2) implies (3) in the notation of the linked question? It would be much better to write out the statement you're trying to prove. Also, the linked question has three answers written. Did none of them make sense? You should explain at least one of the many ways you tried to solve the problem, so we can see what exactly is confusing you.

Yes sorry, you are right. Now I have modified the question, hope it is clear.

Thank you for the observation, I am studying model theory from another book and there the statement of the Robinson's test is as I have written. But anyway how can I prove the hint? Your improvements don't change the core of the problem, do they? Can you help me?

Oh, I see that in my previous comment I had misstated what you wrote. You had "for every $\phi(x)$ existential $\mathcal{L}$-formula, $\mathcal{M_2} \models \phi$ implies $\mathcal{M_1} \models \phi$". But this is also not quite right - it should be "for every $\phi(x)$ existential $\mathcal{L}$-formula, and every tuple $a$ from $M_1$, $\mathcal{M_2} \models \phi(a)$ implies $\mathcal{M_1} \models \phi(a)$". What is the book you're studying from? I'll try to write an answer to your question later today, I just wanted to make sure the question was clear first.

Actually I am studying from lecture notes, but the teacher is following Marker's "model theory: an introduction".

I am still trying to solve the problem, and now I am trying this way: to prove the hint I can prove first that $T \cup diag(\mathcal{M}) \cup {\phi}$ (where $diag(\mathcal{M})$ is the substructure of the elementary diagram of $\mathcal{M}$ consisting in atomic formulas or negated atomic formulas) is consistent (maybe? how?), so that there is a model $\mathcal{N}$ of this union which is in particular an elementary extension of $\mathcal{M}$ and a model of $T$ at the same time. And then I can apply the hypothesis. Does it convince you?

In my opinion, the hint in the accepted answer by Levon Haykazyan to the linked question is not a very good hint. I don't see a direct way to prove that $T\cup \Sigma\cup \{\lnot \varphi\}$ is inconsistent using our hypothesis on models of $T$.
A much clearer approach is given in the other two answers, by Geovani Machado and AnduinWilde.
Step 1: Prove that every existential $\mathcal{L}$-formula is $T$-equivalent to a universal formula.
This is Corollary 3.1.5(1) in Tent and Ziegler [note that condition (b) there is exactly our hypothesis on $T$]. In fact, Levon Haykazyan's hint is a pretty good hint to proving Corollary 3.1.5(1) - I wonder if he was thinking about this when he wrote his answer.
Let $\varphi(x)$ be an existential $\mathcal{L}$-formula. Let $\Sigma(x)$ be the set of all universal consequences of $\varphi(x)$, i.e., all $\psi(x)$ universal such that $T\models \forall x\, (\varphi(x)\to \psi(x))$. Suppose for contradiction that $T\cup \Sigma(x)\cup \{\lnot \varphi(x)\}$ is consistent. Then there is $M\models T$ and $a\in M$ such that $a$ satisfies $\Sigma(x)$ and $M\models \lnot \varphi(a)$.
Recall that $\DeclareMathOperator{\Diag}{Diag} \Diag(M)$ is the set of all atomic and negated atomic $\mathcal{L}(M)$-sentences true in $M$, so $N\models \Diag(M)$ if and only if $M$ embeds in $N$. Suppose for contradiction that the $\mathcal{L}(M)$-theory $T' = T\cup \Diag(M)\cup \{\varphi(a)\}$ is inconsistent. By compactness, there is a quantifier-free $L(M)$-sentence $\theta(a,b)$, which is the conjunction of a finite subset of $\Diag(M)$, such that $T\cup \{\theta(a,b),\varphi(a)\}$ is inconsistent. But then $T\models \forall x (\varphi(x)\to \forall y\, \lnot \theta(x,y))$, so  $\forall y\, \lnot \theta(x,y)\in \Sigma(x)$, so $M\models \forall y\, \lnot \theta(a,y)$, contradicting the fact that $M\models \theta(a,b)$.
Thus $T'$ is consistent, and we can pick $N\models T'$. Identifying $M$ with its image under the canonical embedding in $N$, we have $M\subseteq N$. By our hypothesis, $N\models \varphi(a)$ implies $M\models \varphi(a)$, contradiction. Thus $T\cup \Sigma(x)\cup \{\lnot \varphi(x)\}$ is inconsistent. By compactness, there is a universal formula $\pi(x)$, which is the conjunction of a finite subset of $\Sigma(x)$, such that $T\models \forall x\, (\pi(x)\to \varphi(x))$. Since $\pi(x)$ is also a consequence of $\varphi(x)$, these formulas are $T$-equivalent.
Step 2: Prove by induction on the structure of formulas that every $\mathcal{L}$-formula is $T$-equivalent to a universal formula.
By rewriting all instances of $\exists x$ as $\lnot \forall x\lnot$, we may assume the formula is built up by boolean combinations and universal quantifiers. The induction steps for $\land$, $\lor$, and universal quantifiers are trivial, so it remains to handle negation.
Consider the formula $\lnot \chi(x)$. By induction, $\chi(x)$ is $T$-equivalent to a universal formula $\chi'(x)$. Then $\lnot \chi(x)$ is equivalent to the existential formula $\lnot \chi'(x)$. By Step 1, this is $T$-equivalent to a universal formula.

I suspect that Haykazyan's hint fits into Hedman's treatment ("4.5 Preservation of formulas" in his A First Course in Logic: An Introduction to Model Theory, Proof Theory, Computability, and Complexity; if so, it is too lengthy for an exercise.
